# jQuery.noconflict function($) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in a CMS that uses jQuery in noconflict mode (which one is not important here).

I've read multiple articles on how to use jQuery and I'm not getting the function way to work.

```
// the function way
(function ($){
    /* plugin code */
})(jQuery);
```

but if I do it like beneath and then call everything with $j instead of $ it does work:

```
var $j = jQuery;
```

I kinda want the first way to work, as I don't want to rewrite all of my code to $j (how easy it might be.

The code I'm using (maybe the problem does lie there is beneath here

---

```
( function( $ ) {

// LOAD THE PLAYER

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    var videoId = 'A3PDXmYoF5U';
    var startSeconds = 5;
    var endSeconds = 293;
    var setVolume = 15;
    var suggestedQuality = 'large';
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height:  ($(window).width() / 16) * 9 + 35,
          width: '100%',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': startSeconds, 'endSeconds': endSeconds, 'suggestedQuality': suggestedQuality });
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        var done = false;

// SOUNDCHECK

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            if (player.isMuted()){
                $(".eq").addClass("mute");  
            }

            if (player.getVolume() > setVolume) {
                player.setVolume(setVolume);
            } 
            done = true;
        }

// LOOP

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
            player.seekTo(startSeconds, true);
            done = true;
        }
     }

} )( jQuery );
```

Edit: after some more debugging I came to the conclusion it cannot lie to the calling function itself. It is something I'm doing wrong inside my code. The code beneath DOES work

```
( function( $ ) {

// FIRST WORD SELECTION

$(document).ready( function () {

var firstword = function($selector) {
    $($selector).each(function() {
        var node = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3
        }).first(), text = node.text(), first = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(" "));

        if (!node.length)
            return;

        node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
        node.before('<span>' + first + '</span>');
    })
}; 

firstword("#masthead li a, .logo-title");
});

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Did you try adding a DOM ready handler, your script is accessing the DOM, and the current IIFE is not a DOM ready handler ?

Comment: You still may need `jQuery.noConflict` to prevent conflicts _outside_ this code block.

Comment: @Barmar I'm talking about the code inside the block

Comment: First `(function ($){` is for writing plugins, but i don't see how your code is as much plugin ready as it is `document.onready`, in which case you may consider `$(function(){ /*do work here*/ })`. Second, why are you using `noconflict` and you do realize, to use it correctly, you assign it a var then make use of that var. For instance, say `$j` is `jQuery`, then replace first line with `var tag = $j('<script />', { src: 'iframe_api' })`

Comment: @adeneo if I add jQuery(document).ready in front of the function way it won't change a thing

Comment: @SpYk3HH I am writing a plug-in. So yes, I would love to use this.
+ the $j way it is working as I told, the other posibility is not.

Comment: What do `$().jquery`, `jQuery().jquery`, and `$j().jquery` return?

Comment: I updated my question with a piece of code that DOES work. Hopefully that will make things clearer.

Comment: It's not rocket science, if there is a conflict with `$` adding a DOM ready handler like that outside the closure won't work, but when you add it inside it will work. Now replace both wrapper functions with `jQuery(function($) { code here });` and the problem is solved, the noConflict stuff is outdated and no longer needed.

Comment: @adeneo changing the function to how you say doesn't fix it. Can you post me a page where it does work?

Comment: @SpYk3HH `(function($)` is not just for writing plugins, although that's a typical usage of it. It's useful anytime you want to have `$` be an alias for jQuery without needing it to have been defined globally, as is the case here.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten The way you're using `jQuery` and `$` looks fine; the problem must be somewhere else in your code. What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: @MattBrowne it doesn't prompt any javascript errors. It's like it just cuts off the function somewhere.

Comment: You should get a proper error message on the console if you insert the following line directly after the `( function( $ ) {` line: `'use strict';`. Would you mind trying that for us?

Comment: @Julian Of course I don't mind :) It gives me the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function.`

Comment: That should noth happen with your first block of code. Did you perhaps try it with your second block (which already worked)? Either way, I suspect I may have found the answer to your question.

Comment: Please provide a clear error message, or what is your code expected doing and what you are really getting...

Comment: @php-dev I'm not getting any errors. That's the thing. But it should be outputting an iFrame with a YouTube video. I Think Julian had found the problem. Except his solution is not working. This is what it should do: http://wptesten.dannyvanholten.com/ But if I do it the function way it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DFU92oz3NhyRaUoxYZqN?p=preview)**

I got it working by including all event handler functions into the global scope. That should be enough.

```
(function($) {

  // LOAD THE PLAYER
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


  var done = false;
  var player;
  var videoId = 'A3PDXmYoF5U';
  var startSeconds = 5;
  var endSeconds = 293;
  var setVolume = 15;
  var suggestedQuality = 'large';

  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: ($(window).width() / 16) * 9 + 35,
      width: '100%',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  window.onPlayerReady = function(evt) {
    player.loadVideoById({
      'videoId': videoId,
      'startSeconds': startSeconds,
      'endSeconds': endSeconds,
      'suggestedQuality': suggestedQuality
    });
    evt.target.playVideo();
  }

  window.onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {
    var done = false;

    // SOUNDCHECK

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      if (player.isMuted()) {
        $(".eq").addClass("mute");
      }

      if (player.getVolume() > setVolume) {
        player.setVolume(setVolume);
      }
      done = true;
    }

    // LOOP

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
      player.seekTo(startSeconds, true);
      done = true;
    }
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: OMG :D It works. I already tried something like this. but didn't put window. in front of the functions. WOW amazing :D Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the YT player API requires the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function to be available in the global namespace. However, by wrapping your code in an anonymous function, the function is only locally available. You can solve that by *returning* the function from your anonymous function. Hence, the following should fix your problem:

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = ( function( $ ) {
// LOAD THE PLAYER

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    var videoId = 'A3PDXmYoF5U';
    var startSeconds = 5;
    var endSeconds = 293;
    var setVolume = 15;
    var suggestedQuality = 'large';
    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': startSeconds, 'endSeconds': endSeconds, 'suggestedQuality': suggestedQuality });
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        var done = false;

// SOUNDCHECK

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            if (player.isMuted()){
                $(".eq").addClass("mute");  
            }

            if (player.getVolume() > setVolume) {
                player.setVolume(setVolume);
            } 
            done = true;
        }

// LOOP

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
            player.seekTo(startSeconds, true);
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return function () {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height:  ($(window).width() / 16) * 9 + 35,
            width: '100%',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    };

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: unfortunately if I do that I get the following error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined`

Comment: I have tried to figure out why the `YT` object isn't visible anymore if you do this, but I'm stumped. I'm sorry. The only thing I can think of is that `YT` might only be available in the calling context of `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, which might mean (due to scope semantics of JavaScript that I'm not entirely sharp on) that `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` can access it but `onPlayerReady` and `onPlayerStateChange` can't. In that case it might be sufficient to pass `YT` as a second argument to the latter two functions.